# Como mudar a cor do símbolo $ da variável PHP em um tema instalado no VS CODE

Tags: php, variáveis, visual-studio-code

alguém sabe como modifica a cor daquele símbolo da variável do PHP, o simbolo de dólar($).
 Já procurei e não achei nada a respeito, nem na documentação.

Answer (score 1):

Fuçando os package.json de outros temas, acabei descobrindo, segue o código abaixo.

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "name": "Variaveis",
            "scope": "punctuation.definition.variable.php",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#ff8a04",
                "fontStyle": "italic bold"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```